# How do I edit my forked copy of scikit-learn?

Tags: scikit-learn

I am trying to edit the NMF package provided by sklearn.

To do so, I forked and cloned my own copy of sklearn.

However, I am struggling to import my cloned and edited copy of sklearn as opposed to the standard version. For, if I just try to write

```
import sklearn
```

I import the standard version and not my own edited version. On the other hand, if I try to change the name in my directory to `please_work`, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'please_work.sklearn.__check_build._check_build'
___________________________________________________________________________
Contents of /home/jovyan/please_work/sklearn/__check_build:
setup.py                  __pycache__               _check_build.pyx
__init__.py
___________________________________________________________________________
It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.

If you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget
to build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or
`make` in the source directory.

If you have used an installer, please check that it is suited for your
Python version, your operating system and your platform.
```

I am totally at a loss for what to do and would be so grateful for any help!

Comment: Just downloading and editing wont work. You have to install that too. See [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/advanced_installation.html#from-source-package)

Comment: @VivekKumar I'm not sure I understand the link you sent. It seems to provide info about how to download standard sklearn. I am trying to run a version of sklearn that I have edited myself. Are you saying that doing so is not possible?

Comment: Also a @clmno, what do you mean by "Removed git tag, as it has nothing to do with this. The OP must "make" the package?" What do you mean by "make" the package?

Comment: @seeker_after_truth Let me be clear. You forked https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn and made changes. Now to test it (i think) you must compile + interpret (C + Py). That's what I meant by `make` (google make c file). Go through the dev doc to understand what you must do http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/index.html